# Unable to upgrade in ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, 19.04

I typed

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And I got this

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bind9-host dnsutils google-chrome-stable libbind9-161 libdns-export1104
  libdns1104 libirs161 libisc-export1100 libisc1100 libisccc161 libisccfg163
  liblwres161 python3-distupgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
15 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/61.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,769 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unknown system group 'smmsp' in statoverride file; the system group got removed
before the override, which is most probably a packaging bug, to recover you
can remove the override manually with dpkg-statoverride
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Can any one throw any light on this?

Comment: looks like a bug in dpkg, but here is a possible fix:
https://serverfault.com/questions/548996/syntax-error-unknown-user-munin-in-statoverride-file

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer from http://rickfoosusa.blogspot.com/2012/04/howto-ubuntu-unknown-user-in.html

When I typed

```
$ grep 'smmsp' /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride
```

I got this

```
root smmsp 2755 /usr/lib/sm.bin/sendmail
```

So I removed it using `sed` as follows

```
$ sudo sed -i '/smmsp/d' /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride
```

Now `$ sudo apt-get upgrade` works perfectly.

Comment: Wow, this is the *exact* solution to *exactly* the problem I had this morning, and you saved me a lot of time. Thx a bunch!